# How to Create Persistent Spots Remaining in Sign up Form

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am making a website with a sign up function to sign up for specific classes and I need to create a persistent counter that shows how many spots are left for each class. Basically I need something that says, "if the sign up form has been submitted, find the specific class time and subtract 1 from that class's spots remaining int counter. I have a php validation form and can easily code this function but I don't know how to make the int-- change persistent. I have experimented with sessions, cookies, and mysql but none of them are really what I need. Surely there's a straight forward way to subtract 1 from an int var when the form is submitted without resetting the var. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you want, but if you want just substruct 1,and at the same time have a limit in subtraction, Just create table or fields "maxcount" "nowcount". During registration just compare "nowcount" and "maxcount", if "nowcount" == "maxcount", then not substract.

Answer (score 0):

1) Post your code.
2) hoping that your tables are related, i.e one table for number of courses, and another for userid and courseid many to many relationship.
You first store the set number of users in the course table that has the allowed register count. Then whenever a student submits a form, run a check to fetch the remaining count. From that, subtract 1, run an update query to change the value in the course table.

"SELECT total_seats_remaining FROM course WHERE courseid=xx"
Store result in new variable and subtract 1.
"UPDATE course SET total_seats_remaining = 'var' WHERE courseid = xx"